# Attribute error when loading pickle file in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, keras, object-detection, jupyter, pickle

I have created a config file with the following code for an object detection task and saved in the local disk.

```
# Create the config
C = Config()
C.use_horizontal_flips = horizontal_flips
C.use_vertical_flips = vertical_flips
C.rot_90 = rot_90
C.record_path = record_path
C.model_path = output_weight_path
C.num_rois = num_rois
C.base_net_weights = base_weight_path

with open(config_output_filename, 'wb') as config_f:
pickle.dump(C,config_f)
```

I am trying to load this pickle file in another jupyter notebook.

```
with open(config_output_filename, "rb") as f:
C = pickle.load(f)    
# turn off any data augmentation at test time
C.use_horizontal_flips = False
C.use_vertical_flips = False
C.rot_90 = False
print(C.num_rois)
```

But it gives me the following error.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

AttributeError             Traceback (most recent call 
last)
 <ipython-input-20-c5528d5ef98b> in <module>
  1 with open(config_output_filename, "rb") as f:
   ----> 2     C = pickle.load(f)

  AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Config' on <module '__main__'>
```

But I was able to load the pickle file from the disk without errors in my previous attempts and applied the configurations on the test set.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `Config()` is a class that you created. It will be needed again when you load a pickle file storing the config. Therefore, you need to import it in the jupyter notebook you use to load your pickle file.

Hope this could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to refactor the code to use a Python dictionary. A Python dictionary can be serialized as pickle or json.

```py
config = {"use_horizontal_flips": True,
          "use_vertical_flips":   False,
        }
```